# Replace all strings in array that contain minus character with another string

Tags: java

I ask the user to insert numbers in the console.
Then, I print those numbers but if any number contains "-", it will be converted in the same number inside parentheses..
For example: if user inserts 5 -17 35 -8 ,the output will be 5 (-17) 35 (-8)

The code I have tried:

```
public class Run {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter numbers");
        String s = input.nextLine();
        String[] split = s.split(" ");

        for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
            if (split[i].contains("-")) {
                split[i].replace(split[i], "(" + split[i] + ")");
            }
        }

        input.close();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split));
    }
}
```

But it does not work as it prints numbers exactly as the user inputs them..
For instance, 5 -17 35 -8 and not 5 (-17) 35 (-8)..

I'm new in Java so that's why I can't understand what's wrong..

Comment: It should be `split[i] = split[i].replace(split[i], "(" + split[i] + ")");`

Comment: well, that is what you coded it to do.

Comment: @Stultuske Yeahh, that's how computers work.. They never understand what you mean.. haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are replacing the `-` with your desired format but then you are not storing it back in the `split` array.

You have to replace the following code snippet:

```
if (split[i].contains("-")) {
    split[i].replace(split[i], "(" + split[i] + ")");
}
```

Here is the corrected code snippet:

```
if (split[i].contains("-")) {
    /* Change Here */
    split[i] = split[i].replace(split[i], "(" + split[i] + ")");
}
```

Comment: @TechTechnology Your Welcome. Please accept the answer if it worked for you. :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't do anything with the replaced string.

Simply calling this method won't replace the string directly, it **returns a new string**, which you simply ignore.

```
split[i].replace
```

So you have to do

```
spilt[i] = split[i].replace
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `replace(...)` does not change the String you work on, but creates a new String with the replaced values.

You have to assign the result of `split[i].replace(split[i], "(" + split[i] + ")");` back to `split[i]`.

Comment: So, the answer is (as @user2004685 said): split[i] = split[i].replace(split[i], "(" + split[i] + ")");

Comment: the line of code he posted is the solution for the problem you encountered. What i tried here is to explain **what the problem is**, and **how you solve it**.